Must a Postgres publication be created before a logical replication slot to work with it?
I've encountered surprising behavior with Postgres' logical replication. It seems that if you (1) create a logical replication slot (2) and activity happens in your database then (3) you create a publication, the combination of that slot + publication is not valid.
i.e. if there is any activity "in" a slot that predates the create statement for a pub, the slot+pub combo will not work.
Is this known behavior? It's surprising just insofar as I'd hope either:

the docs cover this
the error message that one gets could be made clearer

Reproduction steps:
create table public.mytable (
    id serial primary key,
    inserted_at timestamp default now(),
    updated_at timestamp default now()
);

create table public.mytable2 (
    id serial primary key,
    inserted_at timestamp default now(),
    updated_at timestamp default now()
);

-- ensure clean start
drop publication test_pub;
select pg_drop_replication_slot('test_slot');

-- create the slot
select pg_create_logical_replication_slot('test_slot', 'pgoutput');

-- insert into any table
insert into mytable2 (id) values (default);

-- create a pub
create publication test_pub for table mytable;

-- now, you cannot connect to slot+pub:
-- in shell:
$ pg_recvlogical -d postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/testdb --slot test_slot --start -o proto_version=1 -o publication_names='test_pub' -f -

pg_recvlogical: error: unexpected termination of replication stream: ERROR:  publication "test_pub" does not exist
CONTEXT:  slot "test_slot", output plugin "pgoutput", in the change callback, associated LSN A/7D3CD9F0
pg_recvlogical: disconnected; waiting 5 seconds to try again
pg_recvlogical: error: unexpected termination of replication stream: ERROR:  publication "test_pub" does not exist


See Deferred slot creation.

Don't do that then. I'd say that the catalog snapshot of the replication slot does not see the publication yet.
